# Bluetooth API for windows not working

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I have used Bluetooth API and I have written some codes. I have used functions and  structures from this link- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362930(v=vs.85).aspx

The code I used were simple ones, where I check whether the device is connected/remembered/authenticated.

Initially, I wrote the code in Visual Studio 2013, in Windows 7 with internal Bluetooth **v2.1**. The code was working fine and I was getting the output properly. (i.e, whether the device is connected,remembered,authenticated). I used this structure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362924(v=vs.85).aspx

Now, I tried that same code in Windows 7 and in Windows 10 with both using an external Bluetooth dongle with version **v2.0**. And then, I was not getting results. For example- for a particular device, I am getting the status for remembered,authenticated- properly, but the connected status is always the wrong result.

So, I want to know whether those Bluetooth APIs( the link which I have attached) are limited to only some of the bluetooth versions / operating systems ? If so, what are they limited to ?

NOTE- I didn't post the code because, I feel this question is about compatibility issue and not some problem in the code.